# problem when using 2 different shorcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem, I am using the "code snippet" plugin in wordpress, I create 2 codes with their respectives shortcodes, the problem is that when I want to use the "modify player" shortcode it uses the "new player" one, only the "modify" shortcode works when I deactivate the other one, I tried changing the names and it remains the same, what should I do? Thank you very much, I put the 2 codes below

```
session_start();

add_action('init', 'procesar_solicitud_modificar_jugador');

function procesar_solicitud_modificar_jugador() {

    if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['dni']) && isset($_POST['fecha_nacimiento']) && isset($_POST['direccion']) && isset($_POST['telefono']) && isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['fecha_alta'])) {

        // Obtener los datos del formulario

        $id = absint($_POST['id']);
        $nombre = sanitize_text_field($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellido = sanitize_text_field($_POST['apellido']);
        $dni = sanitize_text_field($_POST['dni']);
        $fecha_nacimiento = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fecha_nacimiento']);
        $direccion = sanitize_text_field($_POST['direccion']);
        $telefono = sanitize_text_field($_POST['telefono']);
        $categoria = sanitize_text_field($_POST['categoria']);
        $fecha_alta = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fecha_alta']);

        // Insertar o actualizar en la base de datos
        global $wpdb;
        $tabla = $wpdb->prefix . 'nuevo_jugador';

        // Obtener el DNI existente del jugador para comparar
        $dni_existente = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT dni FROM $tabla WHERE id = %d", $id));

        // Verificar si el DNI ha cambiado y si el nuevo DNI ya existe en otro registro
        if ($dni_existente !== $dni) {

            $existing_player = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE dni = %s", $dni));

            if ($existing_player) {
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Ya existe un jugador con el nuevo DNI ingresado.");';
        echo 'window.location.href="?";';
        echo '</script>';
                return;
            }
        }

        // Actualizar datos existentes
        $wpdb->update(
            $tabla,
            array(
                'nombre' => $nombre,
                'apellido' => $apellido,
                'dni' => $dni,
                'fecha_nacimiento' => $fecha_nacimiento,
                'direccion' => $direccion,
                'telefono' => $telefono,
                'categoria' => $categoria,
                'fecha_alta' => $fecha_alta,
            ),
            array('id' => $id)
        );

        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Jugador actualizado correctamente.");';
        echo 'window.location.href="?";';
        echo '</script>';
        exit();
    }
}

// Shortcode para buscar y modificar jugador
function buscar_modificar_jugador() {
        
    ob_start(); // Inicia el buffer de salida
    ?>
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">
        
        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 18px;">Buscar y Modificar Jugador</h2>
        <form method="post" action="" style="max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <label for="dni_busqueda">Ingrese DNI:</label>
            <input type="text" name="dni_busqueda" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;" name="mostrar_registros">
        </form>


        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['dni_busqueda'])) {
            $dni_busqueda = sanitize_text_field($_POST['dni_busqueda']);
            global $wpdb;

            $tabla = $wpdb->prefix . 'nuevo_jugador';

            // Obtener los datos del jugador para mostrar en el formulario de modificación
            $jugador = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE dni = %s", $dni_busqueda));

            if ($jugador) {
                // Mostrar formulario de modificación con los datos del jugador encontrado
                ?>

                    <form method="post" action="" style="max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <h2 style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px; font-size: 18px;">Modificar Jugador</h2>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->id); ?>">
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="nombre">Nombre:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->nombre); ?>" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="apellido">Apellido:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="apellido" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->apellido); ?>" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="dni">DNI:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="dni" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->dni); ?>" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->fecha_nacimiento); ?>" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="direccion">Dirección:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->direccion); ?>" required></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->telefono); ?>" required>
                                <br>
                                <small style="color: red;">(No incluir el 0 ni el 15)</small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="categoria">Categoría:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="categoria" required>
                                    <option value="Escuelita" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'Escuelita'); ?>>Escuelita</option>
                                    <option value="Pre-Mini" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'Pre-Mini'); ?>>Pre-Mini</option>
                                    <option value="Mini" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'Mini'); ?>>Mini</option>
                                    <option value="U13" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'U13'); ?>>U13</option>
                                    <option value="U15" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'U15'); ?>>U15</option>
                                    <option value="U17" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'U17'); ?>>U17</option>
                                    <option value="Femenino" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'Femenino'); ?>>Femenino</option>
                                    <option value="Primera" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'Primera'); ?>>Primera</option>
                                    <option value="Veteranos" <?php selected($jugador->categoria, 'Veteranos'); ?>>Veteranos</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="fecha_alta">Fecha de Alta:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="date" name="fecha_alta" value="<?php echo esc_attr($jugador->fecha_alta); ?>" required></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div style="margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 30px; text-align: center;">
                        <input type="submit" name="guardar_cambios" value="Guardar Cambios" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <input type="reset" value="Restablecer">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <?php
            } else {
                
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("No se encontró ningún jugador con el DNI ingresado.");';
        echo 'window.location.href="?";';
        echo '</script>';
                
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean(); // Devuelve el contenido del buffer de salida
    }

// Registrar el shortcode 'buscar_modificar_jugador'
add_shortcode('buscar_modificar_jugador', 'buscar_modificar_jugador');


THE OTHER CODE "NEW PLAYER" WITH HIS SHORTCODE IN THE END:

session_start();

add_action('init', 'procesar_solicitud_registro');

function procesar_solicitud_registro() {
    
    if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['dni']) && isset($_POST['fecha_nacimiento']) && isset($_POST['direccion']) && isset($_POST['telefono']) && isset($_POST['categoria']) && isset($_POST['fecha_alta'])) {
        
        // Obtener los datos del formulario
       
        $nombre = sanitize_text_field($_POST['nombre']);
        $apellido = sanitize_text_field($_POST['apellido']);
        $dni = sanitize_text_field($_POST['dni']);
        $fecha_nacimiento = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fecha_nacimiento']);
        $direccion = sanitize_text_field($_POST['direccion']);
        $telefono = sanitize_text_field($_POST['telefono']);
        $categoria = sanitize_text_field($_POST['categoria']);
        $fecha_alta = sanitize_text_field($_POST['fecha_alta']);

        // Insertar en la base de datos (crear la tabla si no existe)
        global $wpdb;
        $tabla = $wpdb->prefix . 'nuevo_jugador';

        // Verificar si el DNI ya existe en la base de datos
        $existing_player = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE dni = %s", $dni));

        if ($existing_player) {
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Ya existe un jugador con el DNI ingresado");';
        echo 'window.location.href="?";'; // Redirigir a la misma página después de la eliminación
        echo '</script>';
        exit(); // Detener la ejecución del resto del código después de la redirección
        }

        
        // Crear la tabla si no existe
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            apellido varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            dni varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
            fecha_nacimiento date NOT NULL,
            direccion varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            telefono varchar(20) NOT NULL,
            categoria varchar(20) NOT NULL,
            fecha_alta date NOT NULL,  
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);

        // Insertar datos en la tabla
        $wpdb->insert(
            $tabla,
            array(
                'nombre' => $nombre,
                'apellido' => $apellido,
                'dni' => $dni,
                'fecha_nacimiento' => $fecha_nacimiento,
                'direccion' => $direccion,
                'telefono' => $telefono,
                'categoria' => $categoria,
                'fecha_alta' => $fecha_alta,
            )
        );

        echo '<script>';
        echo 'alert("Jugador agregado correctamente");';
        echo 'window.location.href="?";'; // Redirigir a la misma página después de la eliminación
        echo '</script>';
        exit(); // Detener la ejecución del resto del código después de la redirección

        // Redirigir a la misma página con los campos del formulario vacíos
        //wp_redirect(remove_query_arg(array('nombre', 'apellido', 'dni', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'direccion', 'telefono', 'categoria', 'fecha_alta')));
        //exit();
    }
}

// Shortcode para agregar nuevo jugador/a
function agregar_nuevo_jugador() {
    
    ob_start(); // Inicia el buffer de salida
    ?>

    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;">

        <h2 style="margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 18px;">Agregar Nuevo Jugador/a</h2>

        <form method="post" action="" style="max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="nombre">Nombre:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['nombre']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['nombre']) : ''; ?>" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="apellido">Apellido:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="apellido" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['apellido']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['apellido']) : ''; ?>" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="dni">DNI:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="dni" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['dni']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['dni']) : ''; ?>" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="fecha_nacimiento" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="direccion">Dirección:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['direccion']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['direccion']) : ''; ?>" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['telefono']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['telefono']) : ''; ?>" required>
                        <br>
                        <small style="color: red;">(No incluir el 0 ni el 15)</small>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="categoria">Categoría:</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="categoria" required>
                            <option value="Escuelita">Escuelita</option>
                            <option value="Pre-Mini">Pre-Mini</option>
                            <option value="Mini">Mini</option>
                            <option value="U13">U13</option>
                            <option value="U15">U15</option>
                            <option value="U17">U17</option>
                            <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>
                            <option value="Primera">Primera</option>
                            <option value="Veteranos">Veteranos</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right;"><label for="fecha_alta">Fecha de Alta:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="fecha_alta" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div style="margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 30px; text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php

    return ob_get_clean(); // Devuelve el contenido del buffer de salida
        
    
}
// Registrar el shortcode 'formulario_nuevo_jugador'
add_shortcode('formulario_nuevo_jugador', 'agregar_nuevo_jugador');
```

I want the 2 shortcodes to work without having to deactivate the other

Comment: That is a strange problem, my friend.  Is it possible for you to add the code for the shortcodes to functions.php, just temporarily, to see if they work?  I can't see any reason why they wouldn't work as you intend, and so I have to think it has something to do with the process of adding them through the plugin.

Comment: this maybe the relevant part of the code, but it doesn' thelp much to reproduce given almost everything is specific to your context. Can you share a code with the same issue but without all your specific ?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code on the twenty-theme four theme and I got this result[image]

Here I can see both the shortcodes are displaying their respective form

Let me know if this is correct or not, so that I can debug more if not correct.

Thanks